# Java convert List to Page with sort by field and asc/desc

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-mongodb

I am using Spring Data MongoDb, and I would like to implement a dynamic query filter/Criterias but with pagination and sorting.

Originally I am getting the list of employees using the code below (jpa):

```
Page<Employee> findAllByBranchIdAndDepartmentAndDisabled(String branchId, String department, boolean active, Pageable page);
```

But there is a change that can return the list of employees (active and not), or only the active employees.

I also tried using @Query but cannot make the query filter `active` optional.
I mean when activeOnly is true, add query filter `active=true`.
When activeOnly is false, do not add query filter `active=true`.

```
@Query(value="{ 'branchId': ?0, 'department':?1, 'active':?2 }")
Page<Employee> findEmployees(String branchId, String department, boolean activeOnly, Pageable page);
```

I can create dynamic queries with Criteria and MongoTemplate, but it only supports lists.

I also saw a conversion from List to Page using PageImpl, but PageImpl does not do sorting.

The query can be sorted by any Employee field like `firstName, lastName, username, email`, etc.

Is there any easier/faster/more efficient way of converting a list to a page with sorting?

It seems that I can only use PageImpl but I have to manually do sublisting and sorting before passing the processed list to PageImpl.

Are there any better way?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I've understood correctly but maybe can you add something like `OR FALSE == activeOnly` so the query will be:

- When value is `true`: `FALSE == TRUE OR active == TRUE`, so it will filter by values where `active` is `true`.
- When value is `false`: `FALSE == FALSE OR active == FALSE` so it will output whatever is active true or false because `false` will be always equals to `false`.

So the query can be something like this (not tested):

```java
@Query(value="{ 'branchId': ?0, 'department': ?1, '$or': [ { '$expr': { '$eq': [ false, ?2 ] } }, { 'active': ?2 } ] }")
Page<Employee> findEmployees(String branchId, String department, boolean activeOnly, Pageable page);
```

You can visit [this example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pRNid1KPo9p) to check if it is what you expect.